# Tableselect with textfields

Tags: 7, forms

Is it possible to build tableselect form with textfield in each row?

function nowayform_form($form, $form_state) {

```
      $xsroads = array(
      array('id'=>'PrArcabilPodvoyskaya','xsr_name'=>t('Archabil/Podvoyskiy')),
      array('id'=>'PrArcabilSovetskaya','xsr_name'=>t('Archabil/Sovietskaya')),
      array('id'=>'PrArcabilLenina','xsr_name'=>t('Archabil/Lenina'))
      );

      $header = array(
      'xsr_name'=>t('Crossroad names')
      );

      $options = array();
      foreach ($xsroads as $xsroad){
        $options[$xsroad['id']] = array(
        'xsr_name'=>$xsroad['xsr_name']
        );
      }

      $form['table'] = array(
      '#type'=>'tableselect',
      '#header'=>$header,
      '#options'=>$options
      );
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the options you can put another field like this:

```
foreach($xsroads as $xsroad){
  $options[$xsroad['id']] = array(
    'xsr_name' => $xsroad['xsr_name'],
    'xsr_input' => array(
      'data' => array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#value => 'so you wanned a field',
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cornelius Black. But now I can`t get values of textfields after form submit :). There`re only 'id's in debug window

Comment: just do a print_r of the $form_state and look through the indexed array for the values

Comment: Yes it returned array, but there`re no textfields values.

Comment: have you looked at xsr_input fields?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I did smthing wrong. In form submit function I use debug($form_state['values']);. It returns:

Comment: array (
  'table' => 
  array (
    'PrArcabilSovetskaya' => 'PrArcabilSovetskaya',
    'PrArcabilPodvoyskaya' => 0,
    'PrArcabilLenina' => 0,
  ),
  'submit' => 'Save',
  'form_build_id' => 'form-rMQyk-57iEcfahsZq07K5trGFv_5mrXCM9y3xxUXt_U',
  'form_token' => '32SviDJFO3hYkFwywIHs8ACkqid_RZWmlLPmP2Ktx6w',
  'form_id' => 'nowayform_form',
  'op' => 'Save',
)

Comment: So the point is we cannot submit form elements using tableselect. The only way is theming a form like so: https://drupal.org/node/1587968

Answer (score 3):

Out of the box -- no you cannot. It is possible with a bit of playing around though:

- add the form field definition in the 'data' property of the cell you would like to have the element rendered
- make sure it has the #name property set, since it wont get a name otherwise
- add a value element to your form definition with blank value

and you're golden!

An example definition of a form callback ( called by `drupal_get_form` ) with a two row tableselect with textfields:

```
 function ds_test_form() {
   $options = array(
     array(
      'title' => 'Tableselect element',
      'content_type' => 'with textfield!',
      'status' => 'great',
      'comment' => array('data'=>array('#type'=>'textfield',
      '#default_value'=>'', '#title' => 'Comment', 
      '#title_display'=>'invisible','#name'=> 'comment[row1]'
     ),
    ),
  ),
  array(
    'title' => 'Enjoy',
    'content_type' => 'the',
    'status' => 'action',
    'comment' => array('data'=>array(
      '#type'=>'textfield',
      '#default_value'=>'', 
      '#title' => 'Comment',
      '#title_display'=>'invisible',
      '#name'=> 'comment[row2]'
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );

  $header = array(
    'title' => t('Column 1'),
    'content_type' => t('Column 2'),
    'status' => t('Column 3'),
    'comment' => t('Fields'),
  );

  $form['table'] = array(
    '#type' => 'tableselect',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#options' => $options,
    '#empty' => t('No content available.'),
  );

  $form['comment'] = array(
    '#type' => 'value',
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type'=>'submit',
    '#value' => 'Go!',
  );

  return $form;

}
```

A more detailed walkthrough of the above with some screenshots, and why it works that way is at my [blog](http://www.hexblot.com/blog/drupal-tableselect-fields). The above, when submitted, created the following array structure on `$form_state['values']` :

```
Array(
  'table' => Array(
    '1' => '1',
    '0' => 0,
  ),
  'comment' => Array(
    'row1' => 'Comment field text for row1',
    'row2' => 'Comment field text for row2',
  )
```

)