# How to make a form with latest nodes listing with checkboxes same as in 'admin/content' page?

Tags: 7, theming, nodes, forms

I want to create a custom module for newsletter composer in drupal 7.
To create a newsletter I need to show latest 100 nodes in a form with a checkbox and a dropdown (Select box) to select the section user wants to show the node.

In admin/content page same node listing appears. I need a select box within that check box, So need two elements in a row.

Please suggest me how to achieve the node listing table in a form with two fields and a node title in a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off all you can see how this realize in **/admin/content** page.
The file ***/modules/node/node.admin.inc*** has a `function node_admin_nodes()` 
This function returns form which contain list of nodes. The file has clear description and you can read and copy-paste code from this function to your module with necessary modifications.

Comment: Thanks, That was helpful for listing nodes with checkboxes.

Comment: For showing select box I followed http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/75950/tableselect-with-textfields/82763#82763